# C# Textbox is not showing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

```
private TextBox txtBoxDragPoint = new TextBox();

private void rtbLogicCode_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dragInfo.Item2 == true)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Works");
        Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

        txtBoxDragPoint.Name = dragInfo.Item1;
        txtBoxDragPoint.Text = dragInfo.Item1;
        txtBoxDragPoint.Location = p;
        txtBoxDragPoint.Size = new Size(100, 21);
        txtBoxDragPoint.Show();
    }
}
```

I have a textbox that is supposed to show when the user clicks on the RichTextBox. The event and the boolean condition is fine as it is displaying the messagebox however, it is not showing the textbox itself. Is there something else I have to do?

Edit: As mentioned in the replies, I have made the following addendum but the textbox still is not showing:

```
        txtBoxDragPoint.Name = dragInfo.Item1;
        txtBoxDragPoint.Text = dragInfo.Item1;
        txtBoxDragPoint.Location = p;
        txtBoxDragPoint.Size = new Size(100, 21);
        this.Controls.Add(txtBoxDragPoint);
        txtBoxDragPoint.Show();
```

I don't know if this information is any relevant but the RTB is added as a control of the tabcontrol, which tabcontrol is added as a control of the form.

Comment: Are you trying to add the textbox to the RTB, or the form?

Comment: I don't think you can add controls to a RTB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the text box to the form

```
this.Controls.Add(txtBoxDragPoint );
txtBoxDragPoint .BringToFront();
```

Comment: add this line to it. txtBoxDragPoint .BringToFront();

Comment: Wow that was the culprit haha it wasn't in the front! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `txtBoxDragPoint.Show()` you have to add that textbox to the `form`

```
this.Controls.Add(txtBoxDragPoint);
```

Comment: @SokwhanHuh, it has to do something with the Position you are passing to it, just comment the line `txtBoxDragPoint.Location = p;` and you will be able to see it on the top left corner of the form, plus you don't need `txtBoxDragPoint.Show();`